# Calculating Daily hours between multiple clock events

Tags: sql, asp.net

Need to display multiple clock events in single line with considering TimeSpan. And existing code is displaying only two clock in and two clockout instead of table as is clock event.

Current result with table details:

[image: Current result with table details]

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

existing code is with limited 2 clock in and clock out.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:coreConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="WITH Prep AS (SELECT CAST(dbo.UtcToLocal(creation_date) AS date) AS creation_date,rcd_num, person_num, full_name,preffered_name,government_num,first_name, MIN(CASE event_name WHEN 'CLOCK_IN' THEN CAST(dbo.UtcToLocal(creation_date) AS TIME) END) AS CLOCK_IN1, MIN(CASE event_name WHEN 'CLOCK_OUT' THEN CAST(dbo.UtcToLocal(creation_date) AS TIME) END) AS CLOCK_OUT1, NULLIF (MAX(CASE event_name WHEN 'CLOCK_IN' THEN CAST(dbo.UtcToLocal(creation_date) AS TIME) END), MIN(CASE event_name WHEN 'CLOCK_IN' THEN CAST(dbo.UtcToLocal(creation_date) AS TIME) END)) AS CLOCK_IN2, NULLIF (MAX(CASE event_name WHEN 'CLOCK_OUT' THEN CAST(dbo.UtcToLocal(creation_date) AS TIME) END), MIN(CASE event_name WHEN 'CLOCK_OUT' THEN CAST(dbo.UtcToLocal(creation_date) AS TIME) END)) AS CLOCK_OUT2 FROM TEST GROUP BY ALL CAST(dbo.UtcToLocal(creation_date) AS date), person_num, full_name, preffered_name,government_num, first_name,rcd_num) SELECT creation_Date,  person_num, preffered_name, government_num,rcd_num, full_name, CLOCK_IN1, CLOCK_OUT1, CLOCK_IN2, CLOCK_OUT2, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CLOCK_IN1, CLOCK_OUT1) / 60 + ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CLOCK_IN2, CLOCK_OUT2) / 60, 0) AS HoursWorked FROM Prep
```

Comment: I recommend looking at data binding in the code behind. Declarative data sources are not generally used because they are extremely inflexible

Comment: Hi i was unable to bring the same using ASP.NET coding.Do you have any idea on ASP.NET coding for the same ??

Comment: Start simple. Get a list and bind to it in the code behind so that you understand the fundamental process. In regards to your actual problem if you can get the query to return the right data in SQL Management Studio then it should just be a process of plugging the query into your code.

Comment: Jeremy, I am able to bind the data and display in ASP gridview but the challange here is creation date format is look like this "2016-09-01 06:47:20.000" and  its create each line for every clock event. but my requirements to display the data in single line for each date with all clock in and clock out time as i attached in my expected output screenshot